# SustainSys Saml2 v2.9 Publish multiple AssertionConsumerService URLs in Metadata

Tags: c#, sustainsys-saml2

We are working on upgrading from v1.0.2 to v2.9.0. With the old version, we were able to publish multiple assertion consumer service URLs by making changes to the Saml2AuthenticationOptions.Notifications, like:

```
MetadataCreated = (metadata, urls) =>
{
    if (metadata.RoleDescriptors?.FirstOrDefault(spsso => false) is ExtendedServiceProviderSingleSignOnDescriptor _spsso)
    {
        _spsso.AssertionConsumerServices.Remove(1); // Remove the http artifact

        // If using the generic endpoint, we are going to replace the "acs" with "login".
        IndexedProtocolEndpoint _endpoint = _spsso.AssertionConsumerServices[0];
        UriBuilder _builder = new UriBuilder(_endpoint.Location);
        if (_builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf($"/{RequestParameter.SamlGenericEndpointIdentifier}/Acs", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            _builder.Path = Regex.Replace(_builder.Path, "/acs", "/login", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            _endpoint.Location = _builder.Uri;
        }
    }
},
```

However, now I am seeing that `ExtendedServiceProviderSingleSignOnDescriptor` does not exist in the SustainSys.Saml2 library. How are multiple assertion consumer service URLs handled in the latest version?

Comment: I see that that class was removed as part of this commit https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/pull/939 but I don't see any notes as to why it was removed or what the alternative is.

Comment: Another question I have is... is there an easy way to debug this? lol

Comment: It looks like perhaps `ExtendedServiceProviderSingleSignOnDescriptor` was replaced with `SpSsoDescriptor` and that can basically be a 1-for-1 replacement.

Comment: For debugging this, you need to go to your metadata endpoint. For example, our app's endpoint is at `/saml/federation-sso/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SpSssoDescriptor` basically acts as a 1-for-1 replacement for `ExtendedServiceProviderSingleSignOnDescriptor`

```
MetadataCreated = (metadata, urls) =>
{
    if (metadata.RoleDescriptors?.FirstOrDefault(spsso => spsso is SpSsoDescriptor) is SpSsoDescriptor _spsso)
    {
        _spsso.AssertionConsumerServices.Remove(1); // Remove the http artifact

        // If using the generic endpoint, we are going to replace the "acs" with "login".
        AssertionConsumerService _endpoint = _spsso.AssertionConsumerServices[0];
        UriBuilder _builder = new(_endpoint.Location);
        if (_builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf($"/{RequestParameter.SamlGenericEndpointIdentifier}/Acs", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            _builder.Path = Regex.Replace(_builder.Path, "/acs", "/login", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            _endpoint.Location = _builder.Uri;
        }
    }
},
```